# collection of $m-$frame is a Manifold (Stiefel manifold)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, stiefel-manifolds

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ be the space.

Define $$F_m(X) = \{(v_1, v_2, ..., v_m) : v_i \in X, \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_m\} \ \mbox{is linearly independent}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n} \times ... \times \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$$ is the set of all $m$-frame in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

I suppose that it is (well-known) that $F_m(X)$ can be given a smooth manifold structure, and it is called $\textbf{Stiefel manifold}$.

The only remark from the book I read is that the set $F_m(X)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n} \times ... \times \mathbb{R}^{m+n} = \mathbb{R}^{m(m+n)}$, and since any open subset of a smooth manifold is again a smooth manifold which gives that $F_m(X)$ is a smooth manifold.

The question here is how to see that $F_m(X)$ is open ? I try to think of its as a preimage of some continuous functions, but I am not so sure.

Comment: Hint: If you denote by $A$ the matrix whose columns is $(v_1,\dots,v_m)$, you get a $(m+n) \times m$ matrix. The columns of $A$ are linearly independent iff the matrix $A$ has full rank $m$ and this happens iff some $m \times m$ submatrix of $A$ has non-zero determinant.

Comment: Linear independence is an open condition because the rank is a lower-semicontinuous function.

Comment: @levap Can you explain a bit more how does determinant nom-zero help our cause?

Comment: I think I get it.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana: If some $m \times m$ submatrix of $A$ has non-zero determinant then by continuity the determinant of the **same** submatrix of any matrix which is close enough to $A$ will be non-zero so any matrix close enough to $A$ will also be of rank $m$.

Comment: @levap that's exactly what I thought, thanks for your reply, cheers